# SproutCore Collection Sorting

Tags: javascript, sproutcore-2, sproutcore-views, sproutcore-controllers

I have a list of todos and I have tag property associated with them. On the views, I have a "Sort By Tag" button. When I press that button, I want the collection to be sorted by tag. Nothing is happening now. Below is the code. What's wrong?

```
 In todos.js I have:
 Todos.SortingView = SC.TemplateView.extend({
  sortBinding: 'Todos.todoListController.sortTodos'
});

 and in todoListController, I have:
    sortTodos: function() {
   Todos.store.find(Todos.Todo).sortProperty('tag');
  }

 and in the handlebars view I have:
{{#view Todos.SortingView id="stats"}}
  {{#view SC.Button classBinding="isActive" target="Todos.todoListController" action="sortTodos"}}
    Sort By Tag
  {{/view}}
{{/view}}

{{#collection SC.TemplateCollectionView contentBinding="Todos.todoListController" itemClassBinding="content.isDone"}}
  {{view Todos.MarkDoneView}} - Tag - {{content.tag}}
{{/collection}}
```

Comment: Todos.todoListController = SC.ArrayController.create({
  // Initialize the array controller with an empty array.
  content: [],

  //functions
  sortTodos: function() {
   Todos.store.find(Todos.Todo).sortProperty('tag');
  },

  //functions
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sortTodos: function() {
   Todos.store.find(Todos.Todo).sortProperty('tag');
}
```

should be:

```
sortTodos: function() {
   this.set('orderBy', 'tag');
}
```

Now if you add items, you must use `addObject` and use `arrangedObjects` not just `content`

---

```
createTodo: function(title) { 
    // var todo = Todos.Todo.create({ title: title });    
    var todoExists = this.findProperty('title', title).length > 0;
    if (!todoExist) {
        Todos.store.createRecord(Todos.Todo, { title: title }); 
        // this.pushObject(todo); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent,thank you very much. One more question I have whenever,I add a new item, it adds one more to the collection. So, I have same todos twice in the view.

Comment: I am doing something wrong in the view or what? Here's my whole handlebars template:

Comment: <h1>Todos</h1>
{{#view Todos.CreateTodoView}}
  <input id="new-todo" type="text" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
{{/view}}


{{#view Todos.SortingView id="stats"}}
  {{#view SC.Button classBinding="isActive" target="Todos.todoListController" action="sortTodos"}}
    Sort By Tag
  {{/view}}
{{/view}}


{{#collection SC.TemplateCollectionView contentBinding="Todos.todoListController"}}
  {{view Todos.MarkDoneView}} - Tag - {{content.tag}}
{{/collection}}

Comment: That's pretty difficult to read. Can you either post a new question with your new question, or update your question with the code that's adds your new todos?

Comment: The part where I add my new todos in todos.todoListController is:

Comment: createTodo: function(title) {
   // var todo = Todos.Todo.create({ title: title });
     Todos.store.createRecord(Todos.Todo, { title: title });
   // this.pushObject(todo);
  },

Comment: I can't edit the code, it doesn't let me. I tried 8 times or so. Basically the function to create new todos is above, it is under Todos.todoListController Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: That code is working properly then, I've updated my answer to show you how to stop duplicates

Comment: Thank you very much again. Actually I couldn't explain the problem well. The problem is the page says there are 4 todos but I see duplicates so the view renders 8 todos, it seems I am rendering the collection view twice in the template which I am not doing actually. I am going insane to figure out how todos are rendered twice.

Comment: I posted another question for this issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797367/sproutcore-rendering-view-twice-issue

Answer (score 0):

In the todoListController, assuming that you have initially loaded controller's content from data store.

```
sortTodos: function(){
var query= SC.Query.local('Todos.Todo', {orderBy: 'tag'});
Todos.todoListController.set('content',Todos.store.find(query));
}
```